# Get Homebrew formula install path (including version)

Tags: path, version, homebrew

I am looking for a way to determine the installed path of a Homebrew formula that includes the version number.

Currently I am aware of the following command,

> brew --cellar pig

which will return,

> /usr/local/Cellar/pig

However, the actual install path is,

> /usr/local/Cellar/pig/0.15.0

which changes when newer/older versions are installed.

Is there any way to obtain this information using a brew command or the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Christopher Gentle tips I have made the following function:

```
brew_path (){

    brew list $1 | head -1 | sed "s/\(^.*\/$1\/[^\/]*\).*/\1/"

}
```

Example:

```
brew_path opencolorio
/usr/local/Cellar/opencolorio/1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `brew list <package>` and cut up to the version.

Eg:

```
$ brew list hbase | head -1 | sed 's/\(^.*\/hbase\/[^\/]*\).*/\1/' 
/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.1.5
```

*Update:* See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022473/6335853) more up to date solution.

Comment: For some reason, this now (Homebrew 3.4.10) returns ```INSTALL_RECEIPT.json``` appended to the end of whatever package you list, so hbase would return ```/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json```

Answer (score 0):

I find that the `brew list $1` command in @melMass's function runs too slowly to be used repeatedly in my `~/.bash_profile`, so here's a version that should be faster, but assumes that all package paths are under their version subdir in `$(brew --cellar $1)`:

```bash
brew_path() {
  local p _p
  while read _p; do
    p=$_p
  done < <(
    pwd "$(brew --cellar $1)"/*
  )
  echo $p
}
```

Example:

```bash
$ brew_path pcre
/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45
```